# What does payable in advance mean?

Tags: contract-law, rental-property, legal-terms, sublease

I was just reading this sublease agreenment and find it very strange that it doesn't have a section clearling indicating when the payment is due.

https://www.ilrg.com/forms/sublease/us/pa

The closest it has is

> RENT PAYMENTS:  The rent is $ ________ per month, payable in advance
>   on the ____________ day of the month.

If payable in advance means it can be paid before then, then is it implied it MUST be paid before then?

Also what's the difference between sublet and sublease?

Comment: Does it mean the rent is due on say the 1st or 5th of March in advance for the month of March?  As opposed to after the conclusion of March.

Comment: "what's the difference between sublet and sublease?" Different question, please ask in a new post.

Comment: @NateEldredge http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7318/what-is-the-difference-between-sublet-and-sublease

Comment: Sublet is a renting agreement, where sublease is not -- [see here for an explanation between the two](http://www.diffen.com/difference/Lease_vs_Rent)

Comment: @Soren I see no basis for your assertion in the link you provided.

Comment: @Soren I'm not sure differn.com is a good source as it seems just to compare the dictionary definitions of the words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Payable in advance means that you are paying for services prior to receiving them. Compare with *payable in arrears*, where you pay for something after receiving the service.

In your situation, payable in advance means that the payment you make is for the period to come, rather than for the period just elapsed.

Comment: Is the wording "payable on advanced on the x day of the month" standard? It seems confusing if not ambiguous to me. Technically, isn't it saying as long as you paid before you live there, it's ok?

Comment: Pretty standard. Each period is a month long. You need to pay on day X of the month, for the period to come.

Comment: Very standard.  "Payable in advance on the 20th of the month" means if you haven't paid your December rental by 20th November, you are in arrears.

Answer (score 0):

Payable in advance means payable before the month commences. So, for March your rent is due on or before the last day in February.

Comment: Not if it says "payable in advance on the 20th of the month".  That means your rent is due on or before the 20th of February.  If you pay 21st, you are late.